Troubleshooting Multiprocessing Pool: Serialization Issues with Variables and Global Access Dilemma
I am facing a problem with multiprocessing pool and passing variables to the child processes.

import vmaps_shortcutrun as sc
import ifcopenshell
import vmaps_functions as f
from multiprocessing import Pool

def oarun(oanr):

    oa = g_oalist[oanr]
    id = g_scrow['id']
    ifcfolderpathind = g_scrow['ifcfolderpathind']
    ifcind = f.oaextract(g_ifc,oa,ifcfolderpathind)

    print(oa)

    # do some actions which do not need a return

def poolrun(oalistlen):

    oanrlist = tuple(range(1,oalistlen))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(oarun,oanrlist)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Do some stuff that can only run once and output a list of dictionaries
    sclist = sc.scrun()

    for scrow in sclist:

        global g_ifc
        global g_scrow
        global g_oalist

        g_scrow = scrow                             # result = dictionary of values
        g_ifc = ifcopenshell.open(scrow['file'])    # result = an object which can not be transferred with multiprocessing manager, starmap, partial ..... ->   pickle error
        g_oalist = f.objectassemblylist(g_ifc)      # result = an list of objects which can not be transferred with multiprocessing manager, starmap, partial ..... ->   pickle error

        poolrun(len(g_oalist))

My simplified code has the following problems:
g_ifc and g_oalist cannot be passed as variables to the multiprocessing pool because they cannot be pickled. I tried using Manager, starmap, partial, etc., but to no avail.
g_ifc = ifcopenshell.open(scrow['file']) is a very resource-intensive process, so it should only happen once every iteration of scrow.
Passing only the path to the file is not an option because oalist can have over 3000 elements, which would mitigate the use of multiprocessing.
g_oalist needs to be initialized before the pool because it is the basis of the pool count.
As an alternative, I tried placing the variables as global variables.
This works if I place the global variables at the top of the file and only directly run this as a Python script (without the scrow loop).
I need the if name == 'main': before the scrow loop because otherwise, the pool reruns this loop indefinitely. However, using this if statement causes the global variables to be unavailable to the oarun function.
I have already tried the following:

Passing variables with Manager: TypeError: cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object.
Passing variables with partial: TypeError: cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object.
Passing variables with starmap: TypeError: cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object.
Running a text copy of the entire code in an exec() of a different process (if name == 'main': necessary in the original process), causing the global variables to not be available.

At this point, the only thing that would work is making different Python files containing the code for every iteration of the scrow loop and running them from a Windows batch file. This way, Python would see this as different processes.
import ifcopenshell
from multiprocessing import Pool

g_scrow = {'id': '1', 'rundate': '2024-04-10_16-25-48', 'projectnr': '', 'shortcut': 'S:/00. Projecten/TEST Snelkoppeling.lnk', 'file': 'S:/Snelkoppelingen/TEST.ifc', 'filedate': '2022-12-22_12-00-39', 'ifcfolderpathind': 'S:/Snelkoppelingen/1. Individueel', 'ifcfolderpath': 'S:/Snelkoppelingen/1. Individueel/1. ifc_2024-04-10_16-25-48_2022-12-22_12-00-39', 'csvdatafile': 'S:/Snelkoppelingen/1. ifc_2024-04-10_16-25-48_2022-12-22_12-00-39/vmaps_ifcdata.csv', 'csvpropfile': 'S:/Snelkoppelingen/1. ifc_2024-04-10_16-25-48_2022-12-22_12-00-39/vmaps_ifcprop.csv', 'type': 'latest', 'processed': '', 'thread': ''}
g_ifc = ifcopenshell.open(g_scrow['file'])
g_oalist = f.objectassemblylist(g_ifc)
oalistlen = len(g_oalist)

def oarun(oanr):

    oa = g_oalist[oanr]
    id = g_scrow['id']
    ifcfolderpathind = g_scrow['ifcfolderpathind']
    ifcind = f.oaextract(g_ifc,oa,ifcfolderpathind)

    print(oa)

    # do some actions which do not need a return

def poolrun(oalistlen):

    oanrlist = tuple(range(1,oalistlen))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(oarun,oanrlist)

In summary, I need a solution that allows for parallel processing of objects (g_oalist) while efficiently handling the resource-intensive operation of opening g_ifc, without encountering pickling errors.

You can make your un-pickleable object visible as a global by utilising an initializer as follows:
from multiprocessing import Pool

def initialiser(gList_):
    global gList
    gList = gList_

def process(n: int):
    global gList
    return gList[n]

def main():
    gList = [2 * n for n in range(1, 11)]
    with Pool(initializer=initialiser, initargs=(gList,)) as pool:
        for v in pool.map_async(process, range(len(gList))).get():
            print(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Of course, gList could be pickled in this case but this just demonstrates how you can achieve your objective.
Output:
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20

